# How to find largest power of 2 a number is divisible by using logic functions?

Tags: pseudocode, sparc

How do you find the largest power of 2 a number is divisible by using logic function

for example 144 is divisible by 16 which is 2^4.

How would one do this.

I know 144 in binary is 1001 0000 and I have to use a bitwise function.

But what would I use (and or andn orn ?) or perhaps something else and what can I use as my mask?

I know you have to look at the right most number to tell if it is divisible by 2.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You just need to count the number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: See e.g. http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear

Comment: trailing zeroes I see what you mean, but what logic function do I use to get them

Comment: See the link above - there are several different methods.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `n & -n` or with `n & (~n + 1)`, in case you are worried about running across one's complement arithmetic, given the latter works with both arithmetics.

E.g.,

```
> 144 & (~144 + 1)
< 16
```

Now a short explanation.

The **bitwise NOT** (i.e., `~` operator)  of a number `n` gives `-(n + 1)`. It inverts all the bits of `n`. The number 2 is represented by `00000010` while its negation is `11111101` which equals to -3 (i.e., [image: conversion from two's complement to decimal], see the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of signed numbers).

Do not to confuse it with logical negation.

E.g., `~144 = -(144 + 1) = -145`.

The **bitwise AND** (i.e., `&` operator) compares two bits of the inputs and generates a result of 1 if both are 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Now the main topic.

This is an old tricks that gives the *highest power of 2 that `n` is divisible by*. This means that it *returns a number with a single one bit, specifically the bottom bit that was set in `n`*.

For example the binary representation of 144 is `010010000`. Its bottom 1 bit is the bit in fourth position (counting backward from right and starting at position 0). Thus the higher power of 2 that divides 144 is 16 (i.e., `00010000`).

```
144 & (~144 + 1) = 144 & -144 = 16
 16 & ( ~16 + 1) =  16 & - 16 = 16
 10 & ( ~10 + 1) =  10 & - 10 =  2
 12 & ( ~12 + 1) =  12 & - 12 =  4
 11 & ( ~11 + 1) =  11 & - 11 =  1
  3 & ( ~ 3 + 1) =   3 & -  3 =  1
```

Note that if `n` is not divisible by any power of 2 it returns 1.

Why it works?

The negative of `n` is produced by inverting its bits via `~`, then adding 1 (again, see two's complement definition). This sum causes every 1 bit (starting from the bottom) to overflow until a 0 bit is encountered (let us call it the bit **x**). Here the overflow process stops, leaving remaining bits (those beyond the current **x** bit) unchanged. Thus performing `&` between `n` and its inverse will result in a binary string containing only the **x** bit.

An example follows.

```
010010000 | +144 ~
----------|-------
101101111 | -145 +
        1 |
----------|-------
101110000 | -144 

101110000 | -144 & 
010010000 | +144
----------|-------
000010000 |   16
```